# Python: Reshaping arrays and lists

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, euclidean-distance

I have a numpy ndarray object with the following shape:

```
(3, 256, 170, 256).
```

So, basically this represents an array of 3-dimensional vectors. The dimension of the vector is the first element as it enables one to write something like: array[0] for the relevant vector component.

Now, I am trying to use scipy pdist function, which computes the distance between the entries. So, I need to modify this array, so that it can be represented as a two dimensional matrix, where the number of rows is 256*170*256 and the number of columns is 3 and pdist should return me the matrix where each element is the squared distance between the corresponding 3 dimensional vectors (if I have interpreted the documentation correctly).

Can someone tell me how I can get a view into this numpy array, so that I can generate this matrix. I do not want to copy the data again (as these matrices can be quite large), so looking for some efficient solutions.

Comment: to arrange the array for your purpose do `a.reshape(3, -1)`, then it seems you can look for similar questions dealing with `pdist` for 2-D arrays...